# add superscript in table using tableGrob

Tags: r, gridextra

How to add superscript in table? For instance, the column `b` of `df` would indicate the duplicate index as superscript.

I could think of introducing the values of column `b` as expression, but there may be better way of doing it.

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:6, b = rep( letters[1:3], each = 2 ) )
```

**Code:**

```
library( 'gridExtra' )
library( 'grid' )
tg_df <- tableGrob( d = df )
grid.draw( tg_df )
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating the appropriate [plotmath](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/grDevices/html/plotmath.html)  superscript strings and specifying `parse=TRUE` in a theme statement in order to parse the plotmath expression in the table grob. See [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html) for additional details and examples.

```
# Create plotmath superscript strings
df$b = paste0(df$b,"^",rep(1:2,3))

# Define theme to parse plotmath expressions
tt = ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(parse=TRUE)))

tg_df <- tableGrob(d = df, theme=tt)
grid.draw(tg_df)
```

[image]