# add * or # as superscript in table using tableGrob

Tags: r, gridextra

How to add `*` or `#` as math expression in the table? I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43714570/1691723) where the solution was offered by setting `parse = TRUE` in `theme` parameters. However, it does not work when I use special characters like `*` or `#`.

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame( a = 1:6, b = rep( letters[1:3], each = 2 ) )
df$b <- paste0(df$b,"^",rep(c('*', '#'), 3))
```

**Code:**

```
library( 'gridExtra' )
library( 'grid' )
tt <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(parse=TRUE)))
tg_df <- tableGrob(d = df, theme=tt)
grid.draw(tg_df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote those characters:

```
library( 'gridExtra' )
library( 'grid' )

df <- data.frame( a = 1:6, b = rep( letters[1:3], each = 2 ) )
df$b <- paste0(df$b,"^","'", rep(c('*', '#'), 3), "'")


tt <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(parse=TRUE)))
tg_df <- tableGrob(d = df, theme=tt)
grid.draw(tg_df)
```