# How to write a superscript in the header of an R table?

Tags: r, header, gridextra, superscript

I'm trying to get a superscript into the header of a table. The table will later be used as a label for a barplot. I therefore want to abbreviate some table titles and explain the abbreviations later in the graph legend.

I use the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43714570/add-superscript-in-table-using-tablegrob) provided earlier by [Sathish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1691723/sathish)

```
# libraries
library(gridExtra)   # for cool table
library(grid)        # for cool table

# create example
df <- data.frame( a = 1:6, b = rep( letters[1:3], each = 2 ) )

# Create plotmath superscript strings
df[1,1] = paste0(df[1,1],"^",1)              # i unsuccessfully tried to change the example
colnames(df)[1] <- expression('Title'^2)     # here another unsuccessful try

# Define theme to parse plotmath expressions
tt = ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(parse=TRUE)))

tg_df <- tableGrob(d = df, theme=tt)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tg_df)
```

This gives me
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an example of this in the [tableGrob vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/tableGrob.html). Just make sure to parse the column headers as well

```
tt <- ttheme_default(
  core = list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE)), 
  colhead = list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE))
)

tg_df <- tableGrob(d = df, theme=tt)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(tg_df)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but now I have a followup issue ^^
How do I get rid of the row numbering? I used to use `grid.table(dt, rows = NULL)`, but now that doesn't work anymore with `grid.draw(dt)`

Comment: Seems like a separate, unrelated issue. If googling doesn’t turn up anything then perhaps open a new question.